# Filtering the ItemsSource of MapItemsControl in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

I've got a Store App with a Bing Map Control

I've bound the MapItemsControl to an ObservableCollection with items containing Lat/Long information used to display pins on the map.

I'd like to filter out records for the map whilst keeping them in the collection.
I thought about CollectionViewSource but the Filter property isn't available

Is there a way to only use a subset of the items in the collection without having to maintain two collections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CollectionViewSource` to return the `ICollectionView` and bind it to you ItemsControl and you can apply filter on it as below:

```
ICollectionView _myView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(YOURCOLLECTION);
_myView .Filter = MYFilter

private bool MYFilter(object item)
{
   //logic to return item which passes filter criteria
}
```

Comment: Thanks nit, but I can't see GetDefaultView on CollectionViewSource?

Comment: it is the static method on collectionviewSource

Comment: Thanks again nit, but no. It seems this is a difference in the Windows namespace compared to the System namespace?    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.aspx vs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx ?